# ColdFusion - IE Dropping Cookes in CF11

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, coldfusion

So, we've just moved CF11 to our production servers. Among the many weird issues we've encountered is IE refusing to keep cookies set using CFCOOKIE.

Keep in mind this is only a problem in IE. Seems to be all versions: 6-11.

For instance, a user loads Page A where this code resides:

```
<cfcookie name="myCookie" value="#myVar#" expires="NEVER">
```

At the end of the page I dump out:

```
<cfdump var="#isDefined(cookie.myCookie)#">
```

Result: YES

I then click a link and load a Page B (same domain) and dump out:

```
<cfdump var="#isDefined(cookie.myCookie)#">
```

Result: NO

Why is IE dropping this cookie? All other browsers keep it.

Exception: if I add my site to IE's Trusted Site list then it will keep the cookie. WTF?

Also, the particular CFCookie code we're using has been in place and working for YEARS. Since CF7 at least.

It has also been working on our testing server running CF11 for months. It only stopped working when moved to our production servers.

The testing server and production servers are nearly identical: Win2008, IIS7, CF11. The ONE glaring difference is the testing server was installed with an early version of CF11 and is still running Java7. The production CF11 installed with Java 8. We have several issues on the production machine we suspect to be a result of using Java 8 as we've never seen them on the Java 7 test server.

Anyone have any idea if the new version of Java would change how CFCookie operates? Other ideas?

Comment: It's not an answer, but it might be a place to start in tracking down the problem. Take a close look at how the browser itself is handling the response header and any set-cookie responses the server sends. In more recent versions of IE, go to the developer tools (F12), open up the network panel, start tracing and then watch what your server is feeding the browser and how your browser is handling it.